# change div id using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to change the `id` of the `div` using jquery?

I have `div` with `id` (initially as 'first') and a dropdown (with values 'first', 'second').

On changing the dropdown value, i need to change the id of the `div` according to dropdown value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('div.something').attr('id',$(this).val());
});
```

You'll need to use a non-ID selector to get the DIV with the ID you want to change. In the above example I have assumed a class called `something`.

Is there any particular reason you want to change the *id* of the div? I'm sure there's a better solution. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: i like to change the theme of the page using this. All my content will be inside a particular div. and i have a css defined for that div. on changing dropdown value, i' like to change the entire page UI appearance

Comment: I tried like this and it worked. $('select:selecttheme').change(function() { $('div[name="themecontent"]').attr('id', $(this).val()); }

Answer (score 11):

It is simple:

```
$('#first').attr('id', 'second');
```

Add it to your onchange function.

Comment: After changing the first id, how you will change it again. You have to store old id somewhere, but thats a bad solution.

Comment: i know that, but this is anserw to the question that his ask

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to do that?

Keep in mind the meaning of 'identity'. The ID of an element is meant to be a unique identifier, not just any old attribute.

If you find yourself in a position where you need to change the ID, perhaps your thinking is skewed somehow. It smells ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the *title* attribute for those things. *id* might as well be untouchable.
Essentially:

```
your_element.attr("title", YOUR_TITLE);
```